# converting HTML to DOM object and vice versa in JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a form with a textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="code"><a href='test.html'><img src='test.jpg'></a></textarea>
```

I'm turning this code into a DOM object like this:

```
var code=$("#code").val();
var banner=$(code);
```

when perform this:

```
alert(banner.html());
```

I get `"<img src='test.jpg'>"`, I am expecting the full code (`"<a href='test.html'><img src='test.jpg'></a>"`)

When I perform `alert(banner.attr('href')` I do get `'test.html'`, which is what I expected, and it indicates the DOM object is correct and complete.

What I eventually want to do is work on the HTML, run some searches on the href, manipulate it, and write the result back in the textarea. Converting it to a DOM seems the most logical step for that.

I put the code in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2MvnF/5/)

What am I missing here and what do I need to do to successfully convert HTML to a DOM, manupulate it, convert it back to HTML and put it back as HTML?

Comment: The magic word is probably [**andSelf()**](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) or [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML)? On the other hand, elements inside a textarea aren't valid, consider contenteditable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` is the root element so you get its innerHTML which is the `<img>`, you probably want the outerHTML, try `alert(banner[0].outerHTML);`  see http://jsfiddle.net/9Awu4/

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery object contains the anchor element, but the `html` method doesn't return the HTML code of the elements in the jQuery element, it returns the HTML code *inside* the element in the jQuery object.

You can put the element inside another element to get the HTML code:

```
var html = $('<div>').append(banner).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [that](http://jsfiddle.net/2MvnF/16/) (JSFiddle link) is what you want:

```
// grab the html source
var code=$("#code").val();

// convert to dom
var banner = $('<div>').html(code);
// find anchor and change attribute
banner.find('a').attr("href","manipulated.html");

// back to source code
code = banner.html()

// set content back into text area
$("#code").val(code);
```